# ASP.Net Core route template behaviour

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-routing

I've seen in some sample code that a route template (`"{id:int}"`) on top of razor page causes the links to that page to use another pattern:

```
https://localhost/Movies/Edit/6
```

instead of

```
https://localhost/Movies/Details?id=6
```

My question is how asp.net manages to change all the links to that pattern, does it know about that page before rendering it?
Does it collaborate with other pages when processing a page?

Comment: The helper that generates url check action's `Route` attribute to accomplish what you described. But why do you ask this?

Answer (score 1):

When the application first starts, a collection of attribute routes are built. The routes are built for any Razor file with an `@page` directive in the root Pages folder, and for any [other routes that have been defined via `PageRouteConventions`](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-route-conventions).

When you use the Url helper to generate links, or the anchor tag helper (which uses the Url helper behind the scenes), the link that gets generated is based on the attribute route that was built for the page that you pass to the helper.

In attribute routing, route parameters are added as segments in the URL, which is why the values are not appended as query string values. If you prefer query strings, don't declare route values as part of the `@page` directive.

Answer (score -1):

Run the `dotnet publish -c Release` command and take a look inside the `bin/Release` folder.

You will not find your `.cshtml` files with html in them. What happaned where did all the html go? And how does this relate to the question?

You gotta remember that `cshtml` will endup being your regular ol' `c#` and all that fancy razor templating syntax end's up being `c#`. This process has many names and `transpilation` is one of them performed by [transpilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler).

Okey so now that we can safely assume that when you have a `Index.cshtml` file it will get populated in to some sort of an object, let's call it `RazorPage.cs` this will just store all the configuration for this page. Now let's say this index page is living in a folder called `Home` now we can have a dictionary `Dictionary<string, RazorPage>` and let's say that the `key` will be `"/Home/Index"`. Following along based on transpiled `@page "{id:int}"` syntax, it might generate a template string for the route and store that in the `RazorPage` in a `RouteTemplate` parameter.

So when you use `asp-page` tag helper it will find the correct `RazorPage` and it can know the template for the `url`, populating it with the values you provided.

**I haven't seen the actual implementation this is just my guess.**

> My question is how asp.net manages to change all the links to that pattern, does it know about that page before rendering it?

Yes it knows everything about the page at run time. Most likely the `services.AddMvc()` service takes care of loading in all the razor pages / views / controllers, at startup.

> Does it collaborate with other pages when processing a page?

Highly likely no, unless you mean components/layouts/partials. It will however struggle to resolve a page if you have identical route for 2 pages.